# How to interact with this JSON in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically create React Components based on a JSON const.

It looks like this:

```
const cardItems = { cards: [{
  src: '../images/des-mad.jpg',
  text: 'Some text',
  label: 'MADRID',
  path: '/mad',
},{
  src: '../images/des-mex.jpg',
  text: 'Some text',
  label: 'MEXICO CITY',
  path: '/mex',
},{
  src: '../images/des-ber.jpg',
  text: 'Some text',
  label: 'BERLIN',
  path: '/ber',
},{
  src: '../images/des-nyc.jpg',
  text: 'Some text',
  label: 'NEW YORK',
  path: '/nyc',
},{
  src: '../images/des-gru.jpg',
  text: 'Some text',
  label: 'SÃO PAULO',
  path: '/gru',
},]};
```

I have created this snippet here and put some zeros just for testing because I have no clue what goes into the brackets. The zeros bring me 5x the first, which is a very good signal that the loop works.

```
    {cardItems.cards.map(item => 
      <CardItem key={item}               
        src={cardItems.cards[0].src}
        text={cardItems.cards[0].text}
        label={cardItems.cards[0].label}
        path={cardItems.cards[0].path} 
      />)}
```

I tried `item`, `item.id`, `i` … everything.

Comment: Your cardItems themselves don't have a cards property. I'd strongly recommend getting to grips with basic JS before throwing React on top.

Comment: You need to use the `item` parameter. You're already doing that for the `key` (although the keys will all end up `[object Object]` afaik so you need to fix that), now apply the same logic to `src` and use `item.src` (Also, this is not a JSON but an object literal, JSON is a text format)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks! I was so blind I couldn't see I was calling the cardItem, instead of the item! I am glad to accept your answer if you post one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates over an array. It has a callback that accepts the following arguments: 1) the current element 2) the current index 3) the array `map` was called on. Here we're only concerned about the first argument: the current element.

In this example you're iterating over the `cards` array so the current element will be an object at index *n*. In this example you've called it `item`, so you use that object's properties to inform how the JSX is to be populated.

Note: keys can't be the whole object so, assuming that that labels are unique, we can use that. It might be a good idea to actually add an id property to the objects in the array so you can use that instead.

```
{cardItems.cards.map(item => 
  <CardItem
    key={item.label}
    src={item.src}
    text={item.text}
    label={item.label}
    path={item.path} 
  />)}
```

Comment: `keys can't be the whole object` I think you are mistaken there. You can use object identity for key, and if the items collection is static this would be a very good key indeed.

Comment: Won't objects get stringified to `[object Object]` which means all of the keys will be the same? @Martin

Comment: This is only true for properties that end up as attributes on DOM elements, but not for anything that is processed in the React framework.